# macos stoping docker from terminal

Tags: docker

does anyone know the command I should execute from a macos terminal to stop the docker daemon.  I ran `open --background -a Docker` to start the daemon.  Now looking for a way to stop the daemon.

Comment: you can stop the running daemon by `killall Docker`

Answer (score 0):

You can affect the reverse by telling the Docker to quit using the **osascript** command:

`osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'`